# Image upload in Android using php/mySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, image-uploading

*Hi,*

I've been trying to find a tutorial on how to **upload/download** an image to/from a mySQL database by using php and android.

I've made a database on 000WebHost, I've uploaded string data (name,username,password,email), but I want my app to have the ability to **upload/download** images.

Does anyone know a good tutorial (video/text maybe) on how this can be done?

*Thanks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php allows you to create forms which support image upload functionality. This is generally done via a multi-part post message to a form that you create. Check that out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

You can try storing the image into a MySQL db as a base64 encoded string.
However, this is not a good idea from scalability perspective.

You can checkout this tutorial [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-php-server/) which has an android sample as well.